# jquery submenu show on all li's

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7, less

I try to get the submenu only on the li's witch it contents.
i'm a little bit clueless how to get this working maybe someone can help me with this?

This build in a Drupal7 website with bootstrap theme.

see jquery:

```
/* scroll menu li "based on block" */
var newsLinks = '<ul id="sidebar" class="nav nav-stacked">';
var submenu = '<ul class="nav nav-stacked">';

$("#content .block-block").each(function (index, item) {

    $(this).find('.sub').each(function () {
        var submenu_id = $(this).attr('id');
        submenu += '<li><a href="#' + submenu_id + '">' + submenu_id + '</a></li>';
    })
    submenu += '</ul>';

    newsLinks += '<li class="' + item.id + '"><a href="#' + item.id + '">' + item.id + '</a>' + submenu + '</li>';
});
newsLinks += '</ul>';

$(".bs-docs-sidebar").html(newsLinks);
```

Comment: please create jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wcammeraat/wbfj8u7s/2/

Comment: I have just checked your fiddle, and for Logo and Test li, submenu are getting added properly. What you are expecting is unclear. can you please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, i got it working with the autoanchore js. I will make a fiddle to show what if done so maybe it can help other people. thanks for your time!

```
[fiddle link][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/wcammeraat/rw55b54n
```